# Are the prime cyclotomic polynomials irreducible over any field where they're not obviously reducible ?

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, roots-of-unity, galois-extensions

My question is the following : if $p$ is a prime number, $\Phi_p = \frac{X^p-1}{X-1}$, is $\Phi_p$ irreducible over any field $K$ where it has no root ?

Phrased differently, if $K$ is of characteristic $\neq p$ and has no nontrivial $p$th root of unity, is $\Phi_p$ irreducible over $K$ ?

Note that any $p$th root of unity is primitive as $p$ is prime; so let $K$ be a field of char $\neq p$ with no nontrivial roots of unity: if $\zeta$ is such a root and $L=K(\zeta)$, then $L$ is the decomposition field of $\Phi_p$ over $K$.

Its Galois group is generated by $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^k$ for some $k$, so the question is linked to subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z/pZ})^\times$. The question reduces to : is there a proper subgroup $H$ of $(\mathbb{Z/pZ})^\times$, and a field $K$ of char $\neq p$ with no nontrivial roots of unity such that $\displaystyle\prod_{l\in H}(X-\zeta^l) \in K[X]$ ?

I have tried to inspect the roots/coefficients relations to see what it would yield but I don't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) has a section on the cyclotomic polynomials over finite fields.

Comment: @Arthur indeed, thank you !

Comment: To give the possibly best known characteristic zero example:
$$\Phi_5(x)=(x^2+\frac{1+\sqrt5}2x+1)(x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt5}2x+1)$$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$. All the zeros of $\Phi_5$ are complex and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ is real, so there are no zeros in that field.

Comment: May be $$\phi_8(x)=x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt2x)^2=(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)$$ is actually even better known for many of us, because it is needed when integrating $1/(x^4+1)$ with the partial fractons method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose $K=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]^H$, it should work, shouldn’t it?

Comment: Right, I definitely should have thought of that, thank you !