# Strange proof on the irreducibility of $\Psi(x)$, the cyclotomic polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Some lemma ahead:

> **Lemma** Let $E/F$ be the field extension. Then all F-automorphisms defines a permutation of roots of any polynomials in $F$

---

> **Proof** For any root $\alpha$ of any polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$, it is straightforward that
>   $$ p(\sigma(\alpha)) = \sigma(p(\alpha)) = 0$$
>   for any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/F)$.
>   Therefore $\sigma(\alpha)$ is indeed a root of $p(x)$.

The proof of irreducibility of $\Psi_n(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$:
$$\Psi_n(x) := \prod_{(i,n)=1}(x - \zeta^i_n)$$
It is proven $\Psi_n(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
Consider the group of nth roots of unity, cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

First note that any $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism must permute the group of nth roots of unity (actually defines an automorphism of that group). It is easy to check any automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can and can only map a unit to another. Likewise any $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism must map a primitive to another primitive, and we can identify any $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism: $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^r, (n, r) = 1$ solely by r.

By the lemma, either none of the elements of the primitive nth roots of unity is a root of a polynomial, or all of them. In other words, a minimum polynomial for any $\zeta^i_n$ must have degree more than $\Psi_n$, therefore must be $\Psi_n$. By the definition of minimum polynomial, $\Psi_n$ is irreducible.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Until you know the cyclotomic polynomial is urreducible you don't know that every $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^r, (n, r) = 1$ is an automorphism.

Comment: What @ancientmathematician says. A census of $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphisms is equivalent to irreducibility. Otherwise you can't know that all choices of $r$ are actually automorphisms. For a different way of looking at the weak link in your argument I suggest the following thought experiment. What would change if you look at it over a base field other than $\Bbb{Q}$? Remember that over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ the eighth cyclotomic polynomial factors $x^4+1=(x^2+i)(x^2-i)$. And over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ the fifth cyclotomic polynomial factors. See my comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3039978/11619)

Comment: @ancientmathematician I still don't get this... Why cannot I state $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^r, (n, r) = 1$ as an automorphism? Observe the group of nth roots of unity is isomorphic to $Z_n$, therefore every automorphism of $Z_n$ must define a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$?

Comment: Group automorphisms are not necessarily field automorphisms. Look at what @JyrkiLahtonen has pointed you to.

Comment: Your proof does not seem to use the fact that the base field $F$ is $\Bbb Q$.