# If $\mu_{p}(k)={1}$, $p$ is a prime, is the polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}x^{j}$ irreducible over $k$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity

Suppose $k$ is a field and $p$ a prime. Assume that $\mu_{p}(k)={1}$, where $\mu_{p}$ denotes the group of $p^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity. Is the polynomial
\begin{equation*}
    P(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}x^{j}
\end{equation*}
irreducible over $k$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, sorry, I meant to write $p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde on an unrelated question: Are you by chance related to Prof. Gerhard Burde from Frankfurt University?

Comment: He was the best professor I ever had.

Comment: As to the question, the answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039978/are-the-prime-cyclotomic-polynomials-irreducible-over-any-field-where-theyre-no/3039990). It looks like a duplicate for me, but let me know if you think it isn't.